# Is there a way to bind a key to adjust mouse sensitivity?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, windows, planetside-2

Typically, I play with my mouse sensitivity really high, but when using certain weapons (sniper rifles, MANA AV turret) I want to drastically reduce the sensitivity. Is there a way to bind a keyboard key to reduce/increase sensitivity. I have a Microsoft IntelliMouse that cost about $5, so I don't have any special mouse options that one would have with a "gaming mouse". I'm asking specifically about Planetside 2 here, but if there's a general solution that would work with other games, I'd be happier with that. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built in within Windows to achieve what you want, but it's certainly possible. External applications can aid you with this.

An example is [Mouse Speed Switcher](http://www.gphotoshow.com/mouse-speed-switcher.php#.UUL2ETfTCaw). [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/8432-script-for-changing-mouse-pointer-speed/) is also viable if you'd like to program that yourself.